# How do I say "you can do/find/use A, B and C"

Tags: grammar

Where A = 検索, B = タグ, C = フォロー. I thought of saying these but they don't look right. What seems to be best way to say this?

- 検索したり、タグを使ったり、フォローしたりすることができます
- 検索機能やタグやフォローボタンがあります
- 検索機能やタグやフォローボタン利用することができます

Also, I am writing it as a instruction on a website that these functions are on the sidebar. Should I use 敬語? Which verb should I choose to convert to 敬語?

Comment: I think, if I did not misunderstand your question, it is not a matter of normal expressions of Japanese, but the designated case of web design.
If you show us the detail of the use situation and the detail guide of the function of each button in English, we could give you appropriate suggestions.

Comment: How about the second design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to say "You can search, use tags, and follow." If you're trying to say this in a single sentence as a direction to the user I think that

> 「検索したり、タグを使ったり、フォローしたりすることができます。」

is just fine. It gets across the message that all of these things are doable for the user but only there for them if they wish to use them. Also, it's already rather indirect so keigo is not totally necessary. (If you were requesting that they do something keigo would be very appropriate.)

Answer (score -1):

> How do I say “you can do/find/use A, B and C”
>   Where A = 検索, B = タグ, C = フォロー

I recommend you to use the following phrase in an instruction/direction page.

> **利用できる機能には、検索・タグ・フォローがあります。**

Is [this site](https://about.twitter.com/ja/resources/buttons) helpful for you?
I'll show how to design your site in two ways.
When the button or the word 検索, タグ or フォロー in the phrase of instructions is browsed, a baloon pops up, where detail guide is written in polite form.

[image]
[image]